# Zendesk Symfony JWT

Tags: symfony, jwt, zendesk

We have a Symfony 2.8 based SaaS. We also use Zendesk.
We want our users to be automatically signed in to Zendesk when they are signed in to our system.
I know the solution is JWT.

I googled and found 2 bundles:
https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle
https://github.com/auth0/jwt-auth-bundle

But from a first look it seems these are used to authenticate into Syfmony using JWT, which is not what we want: the user has already signed in into Symfony, we simply need to authenticate it to Zendesk as explained here: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816

Any help?

Comment: Not only they let you login your users using JWT, they also let you create a JWT token, which you can pass along to the SSO system .

Comment: We solved it in a much simpler way using this: https://packagist.org/packages/fireproofsocks/zendesk-jwt-sso

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has awesome features. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com

Comment: @SergioNegri when I do tests in local redirects perfect, but when I upload it to the production server it seems that closes the user's session and takes me to the main page of my site. I use fosuserbundle. Thanks